# Strange Angular Material MAT Dialog Issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I played a while back around with MAT_DIALOG to be able to display forms above each other and used the mat_dialog Module. I read that to bring up an existing form the form needs to be specified in the entryComponents Array. Now here comes the intresting part. In my code i have a form that does is not specified as an entryComponent and it works fine. So my question is there another place where i can specify or set something so a form can be used in that matter. I just want to make sure i take the right aproach

Here is a [StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-49zxkx)

Comment: I see no form in your example. Are you mixing `Form` with `Dialog` ?

Comment: You can put a form in a mat dialog, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: The Form Modal makes use of the Mat_dialog to display the sample form in Modal Mode. My question is is there another way to make this work without specifying the form as an entryComponent to avoid this error Error: No component factory found for SampleFormComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Comment: Both your DialogComponent and SampleFormComponent are in your entryComponents array.  Nothing else would be needed.

Comment: There is no other way.  What happens is your angular app looks through your html to find angular components that it needs to load.  With dialogs your component doesn't show up in HTML so it needs to be marked as an entry component so the application knows to load it.  If you're using your component in both HTML and in a modal it would probably work without adding it to the entry components array but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: This is a good reference to understand why/when to use entry components: [link](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components)

Comment: That shed some light on the issue. If the component is used and accessible via the route module it does not require to be declared as an entryComponent as Angular will load all components specified in routes.